# Unknown options: arn:aws:iam::111111111:mfa/User

Tags: amazon-s3, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to get temporary credentials for my aws account using MFA. I am typing into the terminal

```
aws sts get-session-token arn:aws:iam::11111111111:mfa/user --token-code 111111
```

with all the correct values, but I am getting:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: arn:aws:iam::11111111111:mfa/user
```

I have done this before and it worked, so I am not sure what is going wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `--serial-number` argument. Works for me.

```
aws sts get-session-token --serial-number get-session-token arn:aws:iam::11111111111:mfa/user --token-code 111111
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error. Do you know what else I could try?

Comment: are you sure, you are getting the same error. all i can think of is to update your aws cli to latest version.